# Cannot input Chinese in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, user-input

My iOS Simulator is `Version 6.0 (358.4)`. I have already added Chinese Input via `Settings -> General -> Keyboard`. And the International Language is also Simplified Chinese. However, I still cannot input Chinese in my iOS Simulator. It only shows the English character instead of Chinese character.

Comment: You can indeed, it's just that there are so many letters in Chinese that every letter corresponds to one pixel on the screen and you don't notice them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to switch to chinese input on simulator by click the 'earch' icon on the bottom left of screen.

Answer (score 0):

Condition to input Chinese in simulator is, to set a Chinese region, or to set a Chinese Language. Otherwise, you cannot get a Chinese Input method.