# Chinese input in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, input, ios-simulator, chinese-locale

I am using a UITextField, and want to input Chinese in the simulator.  The Mac's native language is English, which works on all other apps.

When I set the Mac's keyboard to pinyin input, the UITextField still only accepts English, and there is English word completion at the bottom of the screen.

I looked at UITextField.keyboardType, but none of the options seemed useful.

Is there a way to make it accept Chinese？   （There was a similar question four years ago [Cannot input Chinese in iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207662/cannot-input-chinese-in-ios-simulator) but no accepted -- or useful -- answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't change the mac language, you should change the simulator's keyboard language.

From the simulator, go to Settings -> General -> Keyboards -> Add New Keyboard

and then add the Chinese keyboard, then change the langue while typing in the text_field to write in Chinese

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see the Settings option in the  simulator.

Comment: @JonathanRachlin Run the Settings app in the simulated device.